# How to install Cmake C compiler and CXX compiler

Tags: cmake

I need some help compiling this project with cmake. Here is the error message.

```
$ ./build_avida
-- Building for: NMake Makefiles
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (PROJECT):
  To use the NMake generator, cmake must be run from a shell that can use the
  compiler cl from the command line.  This environment does not contain
  INCLUDE, LIB, or LIBPATH, and these must be set for the cl compiler to
  work.


CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "NMake Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:C:/Users/Desk/Dropbox/2012-2013/BCB504/AvidaProject/avidagit/avida/CMakeFiles/2.8.10.2/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:C:/Users/Desk/Dropbox/2012-2013/BCB504/AvidaProject/avidagit/avida/CMakeFiles/2.8.10.2/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Is there a solution? I did try this set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/g++"), still did not work. The answers given shall not work in any case, because g++  & build essentials are already installed. If you solved this , could you kindly answer on your own

Answer (score 26):

Try to install `gcc` and `gcc-c++`, as Cmake works smooth with them.

#### RedHat-based

```
yum install gcc gcc-c++
```

#### Debian/Ubuntu-based

```
apt-get install cmake gcc g++
```

Then,

1. remove 'CMakeCache.txt'
2. run compilation again.

Comment: What is `CMakeCache.txt` anyway? I did a google search and couldn't find much on it. Also, I already had gcc installed so removing that .txt file fixed the issue. What is going on??

Answer (score 12):

Even though I had gcc already installed, I had to run

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

to get rid of that error

Answer (score 6):

The approach I use is to start the "Visual Studio Command Prompt" which can be found in the Start menu. E.g. my visual studio 2010 Express install has a shortcute `Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)` at `Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010\Visual Studio Tools`.

This shortcut prepares an environment by calling a script `vcvarsall.bat` where the compiler, linker, etc. are setup from the right Visual Studio installation.

Alternatively, if you already have a prompt open, you can prepare the environment by calling a similar script:

```
:: For x86 (using the VS100COMNTOOLS env-var)
call "%VS100COMNTOOLS%"\..\..\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat
```

or

```
:: For amd64 (using the full path)
call C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat
```

### However:

Your output (with the '$' prompt) suggests that you are attempting to run CMake from a MSys shell. In that case it might be better to run CMake for MSys or MinGW, by explicitly specifying a makefile generator:

```
cmake -G"MSYS Makefiles"
cmake -G"MinGW Makefiles"
```

Run `cmake --help` to get a list of all possible generators.

Comment: Ah so I need visual studio. The problem is I need a C and Cxx compiler right? Cxx means c++?

Comment: Exactly... Visual C++ 2010 Express can be downloaded for free from Microsoft and is the straightforward solution. If you are feeling brave and you are already familiar with GCC, you might try MinGW.

Comment: I installed visual C++ 2010 Express, then I ran ./build in the cygwin environment. It auto-detected my visual studio compilers. Worked great thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Those errors :

"CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage

CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage"

means you haven't installed mingw32-base.

Go to http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download?source=files

and then make sure you select "mingw32-base"

Make sure you set up environment variables correctly in PATH section.
"C:\MinGW\bin"

After that open CMake and Select Installation --> Delete Cache.

And click configure button again. I solved the problem this way, hope you solve the problem.

Comment: You can get this error on a linux machine too, even with the compiler installed.

Comment: @cauchy, how to solve this problem then that you mentioned?

Comment: @cauchy have you figured it out how to solve this on Linux? In my case I use Ubuntu 20.4.1 LTS...

Comment: @b00r00x0 this was years ago. But from the error messages it appears that you need to set the compiler in CMake setting the CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER variables